# php replace ' character

Tags: php

how can i replace the ' character in php to - in order to save it to mysql database?

Comment: as a matter of fact, you should replace plenty of characters, not only one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://lv.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) !! And remember this function like FOREVER

Comment: or $mysqli->real_escape_string

Comment: @Petah yup. But I believe he is using PP interface

Answer (score 8):

Use parameterized queries.

Comment: This answer can't be stressed enough. **Always** use parameterized queries!

Comment: @Dennis among ones, who recommend it, only a few do actually use it.

Comment: Of course an ORM can take that 'burden' complete off of you. But that's not the point, you should use a system that takes care of it for you. Be it an ORM or juist plain old discipline in doing it yourself.

Comment: I agree. And I cannot agree enough.

Answer (score 5):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string($string)`.

Documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php